# Implement distributed Second Level hibernate cache using Redis

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have implemented Redis as second level cache in my application but i have seen that API is third party API (not implemented by hibernate )
    I have used maven repository

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.github.hibernate-redis</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-redis</artifactId>
<version>1.6.8</version>
</dependency>
```

I am not trusting this API because this was not implemented by hibernate team.

Can you please give me any suggestion ? or any other API I can use in the project or hibernate provide redis implementation (redis cache provider).

Can I used this API ?

https://github.com/debop/hibernate-redis/graphs/contributors .There are six contributors only .

Answer (score 0):

As we implement second level caching, it is always mandatory to provide the CacheManager.

Redis is one of the popular implementation used widely as CacheProvider, so there is nothing to worry on trusting this provider.

You can use spring-data-redis dependency as given below

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

There are other many cache providers also you can go for, few of them are listed below:

> - EHCache (Easy Hibernate Cache) from Hibernate framework
> - OSCache (Open Symphony Cache) (org.hibernate.cache.OSCacheProvider) from Open Symphony
> - SwarmCache (org.hibernate.cache.SwarmCacheProvider)
> - TreeCache (org.hibernate.cache.TreeCacheProvider) from JBoss

So opting Redis as CacheProvider has no issues and it is felexible in its own ways.

You can start looking at [Redis with Spring](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-redis/)